# Is there any difference between Resources.resx and Settings.setting in winform and WPF

Tags: wpf, winforms

I am converting a winform application to WPF. I am wondering if the files under properties (Resources.resx, Resources.Designer.cs, Settings.settings etc) can be simply migrated to WPF application.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the Resources and Settings designers work the same way in a WPF app.  The .resx associated with a Form is however not usable.